# How to avoid recomputing several variables without completely refactoring code

Tags: python, optimization, design-patterns, functional-programming

I have a category of functions 'detectors', that, given a video, a space scale parameter and a time scale parameter, detect some interest points. I wrote a 'MultiscaleDetector' function, that basically takes a list of space scale parameters and a 'detector' function as parameters and executes the given detector factor for every scale.

This is how they look:

```
def GaborDetector(v, sigma, tau, threshold, num_points):
    """
    Gabor Detector
    
    Keyword arguments:
    video -- input video (y_len, x_len, frames)
    sigma -- Gaussian kernel space standard deviation
    tau -- Gaussian kernel time standard deviation
    kappa -- Gabor response threshold
    """
    # setup video
    video = v.copy()
    video = video.astype(float)/video.max()
    video = video_smoothen_space(video, sigma)
    # first define a linspace of width -2tau to 2tau
    time = np.linspace(-2*tau, 2*tau, int(4*tau+1))
    omega = 4/tau
    # define the gabor filters
    h_ev = np.exp(-time**2/(2*tau**2)) * np.cos(2*np.pi*omega*time)
    h_od = np.exp(-time**2/(2*tau**2)) * np.sin(2*np.pi*omega*time)
    # normalize the L1 norm
    h_ev /= np.linalg.norm(h_ev, ord=1)
    h_od /= np.linalg.norm(h_od, ord=1)
    # compute the response
    response = (scp.convolve1d(video, h_ev, axis=2) ** 2) + (scp.convolve1d(video, h_od, axis=2) ** 2)
    points = interest_points(response, num=num_points, threshold=threshold, scale=sigma)
    return points
```

```
def MultiscaleDetector(detector, video, sigmas, tau, num_points):
    """
    Multiscale Detector

    Executes a detector at multiple scales. Detector has to be a function that
    takes a video as input, along with other parameters, and returns a list of interest points.

    
    Keyword arguments:
    detector -- function that returns interest points
    video -- input video (y_len, x_len, frames)
    sigmas -- list of scales
    """
    
    # for every scale, compute the response
    points = []
    for sigm in sigmas:
        found = detector(video, sigm, tau)
        points.append(found)

    # filter the points, currently irrelevant
```

As you can maybe already notice, there is some heavy computation done inside the "GaborDetector" function, that depends only on the time parameter. Therefore, the "MultiscaleDetector" function unnecessarily recomputes these variables in each call.

In an attempt to avoid refactoring the code, I came up with what I wished was a nice trick, but believed it would be vain:

```
def MultiscaleDetector(detector, video, sigmas, tau, num_points):
    """
    Multiscale Detector

    Executes a detector at multiple scales. Detector has to be a function that
    takes a video as input, along with other parameters, and returns a list of interest points.

    
    Keyword arguments:
    detector -- function that returns interest points
    video -- input video (y_len, x_len, frames)
    sigmas -- list of scales
    """
    
    optimization_trick = lambda s_param: detector(video, s_param, tau)
    # for every scale, compute the response
    points = []
    for sigm in sigmas:
        found = optimization_trick(sigm)
        points.append(found)

    # filter the points, currently irrelevant
```

I hoped that the variables dependent only on tau would remain "stored" somehow in the "optimization_trick" and avoid being recomputed. However, when I timed the different implementations, the difference was around 0.02 seconds, with the "optimized" function being faster.

EDIT:

The actual call that takes place is the following:

```
# read the video
video = read_video(video_name, num_frames, 0)
# get the interest points
detector = lambda v, s, t: GaborDetector(v, s, t, 0.3, 500)
scales = [3*(1.1)**i for i in range(6)]
start = time.time()
points = MultiscaleDetector(detector, video, scales, 1.5, 500)
end = time.time()
print("Time: {}".format(end-start))
```

I tried putting all the variables that i wanted to avoid in a different function like this:

```
def GaborDetectorTrial(v, sigma, tau, threshold, num_points):
    """
    Gabor Detector
    
    Keyword arguments:
    video -- input video (y_len, x_len, frames)
    sigma -- Gaussian kernel space standard deviation
    tau -- Gaussian kernel time standard deviation
    kappa -- Gabor response threshold
    """
    @lru_cache(maxsize=None)
    def time_function(tau):
        time = np.linspace(-2*tau, 2*tau, int(4*tau+1))
        omega = 4/tau
        # define the gabor filters
        h_ev = np.exp(-time**2/(2*tau**2)) * np.cos(2*np.pi*omega*time)
        h_od = np.exp(-time**2/(2*tau**2)) * np.sin(2*np.pi*omega*time)
        # normalize the L1 norm
        h_ev /= np.linalg.norm(h_ev, ord=1)
        h_od /= np.linalg.norm(h_od, ord=1)
        return h_ev, h_od
    # setup video
    video = v.copy()
    video = video.astype(float)/video.max()
    video = video_smoothen_space(video, sigma)
    # compute the response
    h_ev, h_od = time_function(tau)
    response = (scp.convolve1d(video, h_ev, axis=2) ** 2) + (scp.convolve1d(video, h_od, axis=2) ** 2)
    points = interest_points(response, num=num_points, threshold=threshold, scale=sigma)
    return points
```

The variables that i want to avoid recomputing are h_ev and h_od. The execution time was basically the same (actually, some ms slower).

Comment: Have you considered using cache decorator, so that value already computed are not computed again but taken directly from the cache?

Comment: @SparklingMarcel that sounds like a good idea, i didn't now that kind of thing existed. I will try it out.

Comment: @SparklingMarcel I looked a bit into it and it seems like these decorators are for caching results, if I understand correctly. In my example, i'm interested in caching the "time" "omega" and "h_ev" "h_od" variables. I won't stop looking into it because it seems interesting, but right now I don't have much time. Thanks for the proposal either way!

Comment: @StefanosAnagnostou Wouldn't extracting the calculation into its own function that takes the time parameter make it so that you can use the cache decorator?

Comment: @Sylwester I read your comment and tried it out just now. Unfortunately, it does not seem to pay off. I timed the different versions of the function and it is at least as slow, if not slower. Also, something else that I noticed is that the decorator does not seem to work with ndarrays. It is irrelevant to the present problem, but relevant to the original, abstract question that i posed.

Comment: There's something I don't get about your code is that you never call GaborDetector in your example.

Anyway, if some of your variable are always the same and only need to be computed once, put them in a function, return them, and then use them as parameter for other function. If you can update your code with the revelant function call (GarborDetector) and then tell us precisely which variable you don't want to "recompute" I may be able to produce a satisfying answer :)

Comment: @SparklingMarcel I'm sorry, I thought I explained it but perhaps it needs clarification. The "GaborDetector" function is passed as a parameter to the "MultiscaleDetector". The "MultiscaleDetector" is designed to take as a parameter whatever "detector" function exists (such as the "GaborDetector" or other detectors that I haven't showed because they are irrelevant).

I think your last suggestion is what Sylwester also suggested. It sounds really reasonable and I actually tried it, but unfortunately it does not seem to pay off.

I will update the question.

Comment: How can `GaborDetector` be passed as the function when it takes 5 parameters?

Comment: @quamrana see the edited question. i can use a lambda function to pinpoint the other parameters and turn it into a function that takes just three parameters. I know the design is far from good, but I don't think that this is exactly the point right now. The point is how to avoid recomputing the same things multiple times.

Comment: Ok, I see that now. But what exactly is the bit you want to avoid recomputing?

Comment: In your example, you are calling GaborDetectorTrial only once, there's therefore nothing you are re-computing, do you mean that in the real case you are calling GaborDetectorTrial multiple time, but "Tau" is always the same?

Comment: @Stefanos Anagnostou – You write "_The actual call that takes place is the following: … `detector = lambda v, s, t: GaborDetector(v, s, t, 0.3, 500)`_"; according to this, you don't call `GaborDetectorTrial` at all, but rather `GaborDetector`.

Comment: @SparklingMarcel In my provided example, the GaborDetector is called multiple times inside the MultiscaleDetector. There is a loop inside the MultiscaleDetector that calls the GaborDetector multiple times, for different sigmas but for the same tau. Yes, the "tau" is always the same.

Comment: @Armali I time the original version and then I change the code to time the trial version. I didn't want to post too much code. Perhaps I should have been more clear. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Oh yeah you are absolutely right about that I didn't pay attention, but my solution of storing in a dic (which is exactly how caching works btw, they just store parameter and result in a dic) should go very well in your for loop (and it's not an unclean way of doing it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just split in multiple function?

Example :

```
def time_function(tau): #To compute hev and hod
        time = np.linspace(-2*tau, 2*tau, int(4*tau+1))
        omega = 4/tau
        # define the gabor filters
        h_ev = np.exp(-time**2/(2*tau**2)) * np.cos(2*np.pi*omega*time)
        h_od = np.exp(-time**2/(2*tau**2)) * np.sin(2*np.pi*omega*time)
        # normalize the L1 norm
        h_ev /= np.linalg.norm(h_ev, ord=1)
        h_od /= np.linalg.norm(h_od, ord=1)
        return h_ev, h_od
```

and then

```
# read the video
video = read_video(video_name, num_frames, 0)
# get the interest points
custom_tau = {}

scales = [3*(1.1)**i for i in range(6)]
start = time.time()
for i in range(0,10): # for loop cause otherwise you call GaborDetector only once so the question is not revelant
    #Insert logic here because for your question to be revelant Tau must not always be the same
    if tau not in custom_tau.keys(): # Logic to "cache" hev and hod for the same tau value
        hev, hod = time_function(tau)
        custom_tau[tau] = (hev, hod)
    else:
        hev, hod = custom_tau[tau]
    gabor = GaborDetector(v, s, t, hev, hod, 0.3, 500)
    points = MultiscaleDetector(gabor, video, scales, 1.5, 500)
end = time.time()
print("Time: {}".format(end-start))
```

and finally you change GarborCollector to not recompute time

```
def GaborDetectorTrial(v, sigma, tau,hev, hod, threshold, num_points):

    video = v.copy()
    video = video.astype(float)/video.max()
    video = video_smoothen_space(video, sigma)
    response = (scp.convolve1d(video, h_ev, axis=2) ** 2) + (scp.convolve1d(video, h_od, axis=2) ** 2)
    points = interest_points(response, num=num_points, threshold=threshold, scale=sigma)
    return points
```

What you do in this code is "caching" (through a dictionnary) hev and hod, so that if you already computed it for a given "tau", you instead lookup in the dictionnary for the result, otherwise you compute it and put it in the dictionnary

I had to extrapolate and guess how your code would work, because in the case you had given, he_v and ho_d are never re-computed since you call garbor only once

Comment: I reformatted the code so that the GaborDetector function takes "h_ev" and "h_od" as parameters, precomputed by the "time_function",  close to what you are suggesting. There is a small but consistent speedup of around 200-500ms. Personally, I don't find it ideal (for design reasons, although perhaps it is easily fixed) but the speedup is there! I'll mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You must define the to-be-cached function (`time_function`) in an appropriate scope, here: outside of `GaborDetectorTrial` - as it is in your code above, the `time_function`'s life ends each time `GaborDetectorTrial` returns, and so does its cache's.

Comment: I changed the scope by moving the "time_function" outside of the definition of "GaborDetector" but unfortunately I still see no speedup. I find it really weird because what you are suggesting seems logical to me.

Comment: Hm - I find it also weird, it seemed to work for me. (I checked by inserting `print("time_function(%d)"%tau)` in `time_function`.)